# NSNotifications and removeObserver in a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotification

I create a subclassed `UIView`:

```
BeneficialsFormView *view = [[BeneficialsFormView alloc] init];
view.alpha = 0;
view.delegate = self;

view.screenView = [self.delegate displayEntityForm:view];
```

The delegate call is to display the `UIView` and returns a UIView that I use to disable background touches (just a UIView with black blackground color and reduced alpha).

In the subclassed `UIView`, I add in keyboard notifications:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {
    DLog(@"fired");

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardEvent:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardEvent:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

    // UI Code
}
```

I try to remove the `NSNotifications` in `dealloc`:

```
-(void)dealloc {
    DLog(@"fired");

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self forKeyPath:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self forKeyPath:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification];
}
```

The issue is that `dealloc` is fired right after `awakeFromNib`:

```
2013-06-12 15:37:39.260  DEBUG | -[BeneficialsFormView init] | fired
2013-06-12 15:37:39.287  DEBUG | -[BeneficialsFormView awakeFromNib] | fired
2013-06-12 15:37:39.339  DEBUG | -[BeneficialsFormView dealloc] | fired
```

They all are fired withing .1 seconds of each other.  The subclassed `UIView` behaves exactly as I want it to; It shows, all its contents work and I can `removeFromSuperview` w/out issues.

I was under the assumption `dealloc` would fire when all references to the subclassed `UIView` reached 0?

I am using ARC.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Found out what I'm doing wrong:

```
-(id)init {
    DLog(@"fired");
    DLog(@"self: %@",self);

    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BeneficialsFormView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    return self;
}
```

So I create my view with my `init` method, which loads the xib file. `awakeFromNib` fires and then the object I create with my `init` file looses reference and is deallocated while the objected created from `awakeFromNib` is displayed.

How can I fix this? Or am I doing something fundamentally wrong and creating a tear in the space-time continuum?

```
2013-06-12 18:15:33.957  DEBUG | -[BeneficialsFormView init] | fired
2013-06-12 18:15:33.959  DEBUG | -[BeneficialsFormView init] | self: <BeneficialsFormView: 0x1f0b1d50; frame = (0 0; 0 0); transform = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; alpha = 0; opaque = NO; layer = (null)>

2013-06-12 18:15:33.988  DEBUG | -[BeneficialsFormView awakeFromNib] | fired
2013-06-12 18:15:33.989  DEBUG | -[BeneficialsFormView awakeFromNib] | self: <BeneficialsFormView: 0x1e58da60; frame = (0 0; 350 400); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x1e5c60f0>>

2013-06-12 18:15:34.044  DEBUG | -[BeneficialsFormView dealloc] | fired
2013-06-12 18:15:34.045  DEBUG | -[BeneficialsFormView dealloc] | self: <BeneficialsFormView: 0x1f0b1d50; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x1f0d4830>>
```

Comment: your assumption is correct, but based on the code posted I don't see who own your uiview subclass..

Comment: In the delegate call I make (`displayEntityForm:`), the view is added: [mainView addSubview:beneficialsView]`. Won't this cause ownership?

Comment: yes but is not on the code you posted, and also why you add the observer in the subclass?

Comment: I tried adding a class variable `@property (strong, nonatomic) BeneficialsFormView *beneficialView;` and assigned, still have the issue.

Comment: and you do self.beneficialView = [[BeneficialsFormView alloc] init];

Comment: Yes (in a different way): `BeneficialsFormView *view = [[BeneficialsFormView alloc] init];` and then `self.beneficialView = view`.

Comment: [self.delegate displayEntityForm:view]; is this method the one that at the end do addSubview? and also who is the delegate?

Comment: Yes. the delegate call `displayEntityForm:view` adds the view. The delegate call is passed through a different subclassed `UIView`'s to a `UIViewController` which adds the view to its main view.

Comment: could you try to actually take the ownership of this view in the delegate

Comment: Ok, I tried but didn't solve the issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to unsubscribe from a NSNotification in a UIView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200775/when-to-unsubscribe-from-a-nsnotification-in-a-uiview)

Answer (score 3):

You're making it too complicated. Just go simple with it:

1.) Load base view

2.) Check criteria for whether you need to display the view to disable background touches

3.) If so, just overlay the gradient as a subview. Remove the NSNotificationCenter observer when a user presses a button to leave the view. Do **NOT** remove it inside of dealloc. It is often delayed and you will see this same problem occur.

Comment: Ok, that seems like a viable solution. I guess the over arching concern is that the code is creating 2 instances of the object; once in the `init` method (which gets released right away) and one in the `awakeFromNib` method that is called from the `init` method.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for an answer for the similar question,i found two methods where we can add and remove observer.
Just to show the updated APIs,for them who are looking for this.

This is called before the view is added to to a window. It also will be called when the view is removed from its window.

```
- (void)willMoveToWindow:(UIWindow *)newWindow {
    if (newWindow == nil) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:
                                                        name:
                                                      object:];
     }
}
```

Below method is called immediately after its window property gets set.

```
-(void)didMoveToWindow {
        if (self.window) {
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:
                                                     selector: 
                                                         name:
                                                       object:];
        }
    }
```